# Android - value results to "infinity" when multiplied by value fetched from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Iam trying to fetch a value from the last row in my sqlite database and use it for multiplication and division in my main activity to get a certain result. But I get the multiplication result as 0 and division result as "infinity". Can anyone help!!

heres the code

```
 food.java (main activity)
    {

               //user inputs
                ETRate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETRate);
        ETFoodQty =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETFoodQty;
                ETRate.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        ETFoodQty.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

                FoodStorage foodGetInfo = new FoosStorage(this);
            foodGetInfo.open();
            foodGetInfo.getAvgTotal(this);
            foodGetInfo.close();
                chkLastTotal1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isChkLastTotal1=true;
            }
        });


public void onFocusChange(View predictionFocusView, boolean hasPredictionETFocus) 
    {
        if(ETRate.isFocused())
                    {
                        if(foodQty!=0) //here I get rate =0
                        {
                            rate =(long) (lastTotal*foodQty);
                            setRate(rate);
                            ETRate.setText(String.valueOf(rate));

                        }
                    }
                    else if(foodQty.isFocused()) //Here I get foodQty = infinity
                    {
                        if(rate!=0)
                        {
                            foodQty =rate/avgtotal;
                            setPredictFoodQty(foodQty);
                            ETfoodQty.setText(String.valueOf(foodQty));
                        }
    }

    foodStorage.java (database file)

        public void getAvgtotal(food pd) 
            {

                String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_RATE, KEY_FOOD_QTY, KEY_FOOD_PRICE, KEY_QUALITY, KEY_TOTAL, KEY_DATE,KEY_GRADE};

                if(pd.isChkLastTotal1()==true)
                {

                    Cursor c= ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM food_table ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1", null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)
                    {
                    c.moveToLast();
                    String getLastTotal =c.getString(5);
                    food myFoodInfo = new Food();  
          myFoodInfo.setavgTotal(Double.parseDouble(getLastTotal));
                    }
                    c.close();
                }


                }
```

Comment: 1) If you need only one column you should only ask for this column in the query (otherwise you have to hope that 5th column is really the one you wanted) 2) If value was stored as float number in database, don't get it out as string. If value was stored as string, then why? 3) There may be problems with different decimal points

Comment: Thanx for replying. The thing is Iam getting the data right from the database but when I try to multiply or divide it by values obtained from the user i get 0 and infinity. Can't figure out why?

Comment: please post code the where you are getting values from user !

Comment: @Tarsem I have included the code for user inputs

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar ok let me check !

Comment: @Tarsem Thanks for your time. It was a dumb mistake which i corrected with the help of the comment from Marcin Gawel

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
food myFoodInfo = new Food();  
myFoodInfo.setavgTotal(Double.parseDouble(getLastTotal));
```

You are creating new Food object

Why don't you set values to pd passing here:

```
public void getAvgtotal(food pd)
```